# Find Item in List when particular financial value is reached

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda

I have a list of sales.

I also have a decimal list of Financial Milestones, e.g. $100, $250, $500, etc.

I'm trying to find the point in time when a product reaches these milestones. What I'm trying to do below, is get my list of already retrieved productSales into a structure I can use (the actual query performs currency conversions, etc. I'm just trying to keep this question simple), so for each milestone, I convert it to this BusinessPlanningElement list and group by DateSold.

I then order it by DateSold, and the idea is that I retrieve the first element that is equal to, or greater than the decimal milestone variable. I continue on then to get the date, and find the different between the DateSold, and the Date the product was submitted to the system.

```
foreach (decimal milestone in milestones)
{
    List<BusinessPlanningElement> MileStoneSales = (from sale in productSales
                      group sale by sale.DateSold into ds
                      select new BusinessPlanningElements
                      {
                          DateSold = ds.Key,
                          TotalSales = ds.Sum(it => it.TotalProductCut.HasValue ? it.TotalProductCut.Value : 0),
                      }).OrderBy(s => s.DateSold).ToList();


    BusinessPlanningElement bpe = MileStoneSales.Where(mss => mss.TotalSales >= milestone)
                                                .FirstOrDefault();

    if (bpe != null)
    {
        DateTime DateReached = bpe.DateSold;
        TimeSpan ts = DateReached - product.DateTimeSubmitted.Value;
        int NumberOfDays = ts.Days;

        //Output NumberOfDays
    }
    else
    {
        //Do Something Else
    }

}
```

If I debug through, I can see the list, and see the item in the list that should be retrieved from this query:

```
BusinessPlanningElement bpe = MileStoneSales.Where(mss => mss.TotalSales >= milestone)
                                            .FirstOrDefault();
```

It seems to ignore it however, and returns a null value to me.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can structure my query to retrieve the first element in the list where the TotalSales are equal to, or greater than the decimal milestone?

Comment: If the list has an item that has a TotalSales figure >= milestone then it would have returned it. Can you put in a screenshot of the list with the relevant items showing in case there is something about the data structure that is funny? If you generate a static list for MileStoneSales does that work as expected?

Comment: Just to be clear, you can look at the `MileStoneSales` list and see an element where `TotalSales` is >= `milestone`?

Comment: Tangentially, you probably want `int NumberOfDays = ts.TotalDays;` later on.

Comment: @breischl: If he is putting it in an `int` will that not be the same thing?

Comment: @Chris I think my problem is that in my list, I group by DateSold, but am not accumulating (summing) the sales as I go, therefore it never knows when the value is greater than the milestone (because it never is).

Comment: Ah. When you said you could see the value in the list that should be returned I assumed you meant there was a valid value in `MileStoneSales`. I did notice that but assumed you were just looking for something that beat the threshold on a day. Is your question then how do you do a cumulative sum of the values? (if so you might want to edit the question to clarify)

Comment: @Chris - I've had bugs related to using `Hours` vs `TotalHours`, `Minutes` vs `TotalMinutes` etc. So now I'm really paranoid about using those. But you're right that in this case there's no difference between `Days` and `TotalDays`. My mistake.

Comment: Yeah, its definitely important to get it right for those other ones since they ignore the "carry over" to the larger unit of time. Days as largest though only differs in the less significant portions (ie the decimal part) so if casting to int its all the same (details for the benefit of others reading who might not be as familiar with the problems).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [`.SkipWhile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.skipwhile.aspx).

```
List<BusinessPlanningElement> MileStoneSales = (from sale in productSales
                  group sale by sale.DateSold into ds
                  select new BusinessPlanningElements
                  {
                      DateSold = ds.Key,
                      TotalSales = ds.Sum(it => it.TotalProductCut.HasValue ? it.TotalProductCut.Value : 0),
                  }).OrderBy(s => s.DateSold).ToList();

decimal accumulatedSales = 0;
BusinessPlanningElement bpe = MileStoneSales
                                .SkipWhile(mss => {
                                        accumulatedSales += mss.TotalSales;
                                        return accumulatedSales < milestone;
                                 })
                                .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

I took the liberty of refactoring your code a bit here. As written, you would recompute the totals for each milestone, but it makes more sense to compute the running totals just once and then examine them to find each milestone. I believe this works, but of course please test it.

```
//Order the sales info by date. If it's already ordered then remove this.
productSales = productSales.OrderBy(ps => ps.DateSold).ToList();

//Compute a list of dates, with total sales up to that date
decimal runningTotal = 0m;
var salesRunningTotals = (from sale in productSales
                            select new
                            {
                                DateSold = sale.DateSold,
                                TotalSalesToDate = (runningTotal += (sale.TotalProductCut ?? 0))
                            })
                            .ToList(); 

foreach (decimal milestone in milestones)
{
    //Find the date we reached that milestone
    //If you're going to have a *lot* of dates you could remember the index of the last milestone
    //and start looking for the next one at that index
    var dateReached = (from rt in salesRunningTotals
                        where rt.TotalSalesToDate >= milestone
                        select rt.DateSold).FirstOrDefault();

    if (dateReached != null)
    {
        var bpe = productSales.Where(ps => ps.DateSold == dateReached).FirstOrDefault();

        if (bpe != null)
        {
            DateTime DateReached = bpe.DateSold;
            TimeSpan ts = DateReached - bpe.DateTimeSubmitted.Value;
            int NumberOfDays = ts.Days;

            //Output NumberOfDays
        }
        else
        {
            //Do Something Else
        }
    } 
}
```

Another possible improvement - if you haven't reached a particular milestone (say, 100) then you obviously haven't reached the higher ones. You could remember that and skip the search for future loop iterations.